# Почему в этом предложении нужна запятая? "Поэтому я нашла сайт, на котором конкурсы"

Tags: пунктуация

Почему в этом предложении нужна запятая? "Поэтому  я нашла сайт, на котором конкурсы"

Comment: Это не похоже на предложение.

Answer (score 1):

Перед словом "который" нужна запятая, потому что она отделяет придаточную часть сложноподчинённого предложения

> В придаточных частях сложноподчиненного предложения используются союзы
>   и союзные слова <...> который, <...> и др.
>   Придаточная часть в сложноподчиненном предложении выделяется запятыми
>   с двух сторон, если стоит внутри главной части; если же придаточная
>   часть стоит перед главной частью или после нее, то отделяется от нее
>   запятой

В предложении из вопроса явно допущена ошибка. Не хватает сказуемого в подчинённом предложении. Конкурсы что? Проходили, например. Если же сказуемое, исходя из специфики фразы, либо для достижения какого-то эффекта опускают, то логично писать на его месте длинное тире.

Comment: Вероятнее всего пропущено «есть»: «…на котором [есть] конкурсы». Но вот к тире у меня вопрос. Я на всякий случай проштудировал в Правилах русской орфографии и пунктуации параграфы посвященные тире, но не нашёл случаев применения тире вместо пропущенного сказуемого. В чём логика, почему логично использовать тире? Приведите, пожалуйста, примеры.

Comment: @Naeel Maqsudov у Горького есть такие цитаты: «По небу — осень, по лицу Гришки — весна»; логика мне понятна: нет слова, нужно его чем-то обозначить; а конкретного правила я не знаю. Полагаюсь иногда на интуицию, иногда на логику.

Comment: в этих примерах из Горького сказуемое выражено существительным. В предложении из вопроса ситуация другая. Что-то я сомневаюсь, чтобы здесь было бы оправдано тире.

Comment: Не соглашусь. В этом примере нет сказуемого, оно пропущено, а вместо него использовано тире. Трудно восстановить пропущенный глагол, но что-то вроде "по небу движет осень, по лицу Гришки расцветает весна". Ситуации с пропущенным сказуемым описаны у Лопатина: 
 http://orthographia.ru/punctum_uk.php?rid=54